# Blackberry - Making auto-update news content with ListField

Tags: multithreading, blackberry, auto-update, listfield

I try to make an auto-update feature with my RSS reader application, so it will send request in every time set, without make any execution like click any button.

I've made a feed aggregator using list field like this:

```
int i=0;
while (i<vec.size()){
    row = new TableRowManager();
    prov = new LabelField(((BinNews)vec.elementAt(i)).getProv(),DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS){
        protected void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.ORANGERED);
            super.paint(g);
        }
    };
    title = new LabelField(((BinNews)vec.elementAt(i)).getTitle(),DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS){
        protected void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            super.paint(g);
        }
    };
    desc = new LabelField(((BinNews)vec.elementAt(i)).getDesc(),DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS){
        protected void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            super.paint(g);
        }
    };
    date = new LabelField(((BinNews)vec.elementAt(i)).getDate(),DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS){
        protected void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.ORANGERED);
            super.paint(g);
        }
    };
    link = new LabelField(((BinNews)vec.elementAt(i)).getLink(),DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS){
        protected void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            super.paint(g);
        }
    };
    rows.addElement(row);
    setSize(rows.size());
    row.add(prov);
    row.add(date);
    row.add(title);
    row.add(desc);
    i++;
}
```

Please advise what should I do to make it updated automatically. Thanks!

Comment: try to look on Push notification

Comment: Having a sample in our Black berry samples

Comment: but it don't give any result when i run it. there is only "HTTP Listen object started" words.
and there is a JVM error ClassCastException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally i can simply use:

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new MainList());
    }
},120000, true);
```